# Django models: Defining str_method based on ordering of one-to-many relationships in reverse-relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I've got a model `Stem` which has a one-to-many relationship with the model `Question` (one Stem contains many Questions).

I want to define the `__str__` method for `Question` so that it returns something like "stem.title + index of the question in that stem". For example, if the Stem is called "Foo", I want the str method for all questions in that stem to return as follows:

- First question: "Foo-1"
- Second question: "Foo-2"
- nth question: "Foo-n"

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Models.py

```
class Stem(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     stem = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Question(Updated):  
    stem = models.ForeignKey(
        Stem, related_name='question', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return **What do I put here**
```

Comment: You should add a field to the `Question` model for ordering if you want something like that. (One may want to change the order, plus the pk / id of the table itself is not suitable for this purpose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to query for the ids of the other questions and look up the id of the current question in that list. There are a few other cases to handle as well where `stem` is null or the `Question` is unsaved:

```py
def __str__(self):
    # handle the case where stem is null
    if self.stem is None:
        return "Question for unknown stem"  # or whatever you prefer
    # handle the case where the Question is unsaved
    if self.id is None:
        return f"{self.stem.title}-unsaved"  # or whatever you prefer
    # make sure you order the self.stem.question queryset
    # so you have a consistently ordered result. Not sure if id is the correct
    # ordering here but there are not many other options
    question_ids = list(self.stem.question.order_by("id").values_list("id", flat=True))
    my_index = question_ids.index(self.id) + 1  # adding 1 based on your requirements
    return f"{self.stem.title}-{my_index}"
```

You could also consider using a window function with row_number, but I think the above is probably a better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a good method to do this can be the following:

```
# Assuming that the value of index is the nth value which is referred in the queryset
# specific to the question with the stem value
class Question(Updated):  
    stem = models.ForeignKey(
        Stem, related_name='question', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_index(self):
        stem_obj = self.stem
        questions = stem_obj.question.all()
        counter=0
        for question in questions:
            counter+=1
            if question==self:
                return counter

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.stem.title}-{self.get_index()}"
```